# How to classify one column's value by other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to classify one data based on a dataframe of standard. 
The standard like df1, and I want to classify df2 based on df1.

```
df1:
PAUCode     SubClass
1           RA
2           RB
3           CZ

df2:
PAUCode     SubClass
2           non      
2           non
2           non
3           non
1           non
2           non
3           non
```

I want to get the df2 like as below:

```
expected result:

PAUCode     SubClass
2           RB      
2           RB
2           RB
3           CZ
1           RA
2           RB
3           CZ
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
`fillna`

```
df2 = df2.replace('non', np.nan)

df2.set_index('PAUCode').SubClass\
       .fillna(df1.set_index('PAUCode').SubClass)

PAUCode
2    RB
2    RB
2    RB
3    CZ
1    RA
2    RB
3    CZ
Name: SubClass, dtype: object
```

---

**Option 2**
`map`

```
df2.PAUCode.map(df1.set_index('PAUCode').SubClass)

0    RB
1    RB
2    RB
3    CZ
4    RA
5    RB
6    CZ
Name: PAUCode, dtype: object
```

---

**Option 3**
`merge`

```
df2[['PAUCode']].merge(df1, on='PAUCode')

   PAUCode SubClass
0        2       RB
1        2       RB
2        2       RB
3        2       RB
4        3       CZ
5        3       CZ
6        1       RA
```

Note here the order of the data changes, but the answer remains the same.

Comment: Sorry for my bother, when I use your method 1, I found one problem: if PAUCode has same value, it cannot be index, is there any way to slove it ?

Comment: @yuchenhuang the solution depends on your expected behaviour. My advice is to open a new question and describe your new problem in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Let us using `reindex`

```
df1.set_index('PAUCode').reindex(df2.PAUCode).reset_index()
Out[9]: 
   PAUCode SubClass
0        2       RB
1        2       RB
2        2       RB
3        3       CZ
4        1       RA
5        2       RB
6        3       CZ
```